# What is the correct mapping of inverse bind matrices?

Tags: animation, graphics, 3d, gltf, skeletal-mesh

A glTF file defines, for each skin, an array of inverse bind matrices and a list of joints.

Let's assume the list of joints is:

{2,5,7,4,3,6}

If we shift it so that the indices start at 0 we get

{0,3,5,2,1,4}

In this scenario `inverse_matrix[2]` can refer to one of two things. It can either refer to the second joint in the array, that is to say, joint 5, or to joint 2.

This exact same question applies to the weights array.

Put in a different way. If one takes the data as is from the gltf file and loads the buffers into a shader. I need to figure out how to map a vertex index in the shader to its corresponding 4 skin matrices.

So if `joints[2] maps to (3,1,0,0)`

I need to know whether I am supposed to be fetching the inverse bind matrices at `ibm[3]` and `ibm[1]` or `ibm[2]` and `ibm[3]` (Since the value at `joints[3]` is 2).

I hope this is not confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[glTF 2.0 specification § Skins](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#skins) says (emphasis mine)

> Each skin is defined by the `inverseBindMatrices` property (which points to an accessor with IBM data), used to bring coordinates being skinned into the same space as each joint; and a `joints` array property that lists the nodes indices used as joints to animate the skin. **The order of joints is defined in the `skin.joints` array and it must match the order of `inverseBindMatrices` data.**

That directly answers your question.  I'll give a more detailed explanation here:

- There're two IDs: node ID and joint ID
- Node ID: Index of a node in the `nodes` array
- Joint ID: Index of a joint in the `joints` array

  - A joint in the `joints` array is specified with the node ID; the joint ID is different though

```json
    "nodes" : [
        {                           // 0
            "name" : "Cave"
        },
        {                           // 1
            "name" : "TailBone",
        },
        // snipped for brievity
        {                           // 29
            "name" : "Root"
        }
    ],
    "skins" : [
        {
            "inverseBindMatrices" : 6,
            "joints" : [
                29,
                1,
            ]
        }
    ]
```

For this `.glTF`, `inverseBindMatrix[0]` would be for `joint[0]`, this joint is given by node 29; `inverseBindMatrix[1]` would be for `joint[1]`, this joing is given by node 1.

> If we shift it so that the indices start at 0 we get
>
> {0,3,5,2,1,4}

I don't think this is correct.  Why do you shift?  You basically just need a mapping between node ID to bone ID until you digest and load the glTF data into your own structures (after which node IDs have no use unlike bone IDs)

```
Node   Bone
29      0
1       1
```

When you calculate the `skin` matrix, make sure you follow the order of the `joints` array.  In the above example, `skin[0]` should be for `joints[0]` i.e. for node 29.